# Retrieve mapping values in a struct in an array in another contract?

Tags: solidity

Tried some things like this but it doesn't work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


contract One {
    Two two = new Two();

    constructor() public{
    }

    function getOldBox(uint _id) public view returns (uint256, bool) {
        return two.boxes(_id);
    }

    function getOldBoxmapping(uint _id, address asdf) public view returns (uint){
        return two.boxes(_id).testmapping[asdf];
    }
}

contract Two{

    struct Box {
        uint256 id;
        bool isFull;
        mapping(address=>uint) testmapping;
    }
    Box[] public boxes;
    
    function setmappingvalue(address asdf, uint someuint) public {
        boxes[boxes.length-1].testmapping[asdf] = someuint;
    } 

    constructor() public {
        boxes.push(Box(0, false));
        boxes.push(Box(1, true));
    }
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because mapping can have only `storage` data location and it cannot be returned from external / public function viz doc:

> Mappings can only have a data location of storage and thus are allowed for state variables, as storage reference types in functions, or as parameters for library functions. They cannot be used as parameters or return parameters of contract functions that are publicly visible. These restrictions are also true for arrays and structs that contain mappings.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html?highlight=calldata#mapping-types